# Number of subsets of $A= \{1, ∅, \{∅\}\}?$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

hi i need know How many sub-sets are there of the set $$A = \{1, ∅, \{∅\}\}$$

and and is there any set having nine sub-assemblies?

i try

$2^n = 2^3= 8$

You can tell me that whole missing? I have these:

i have:

1. {1}
2. {∅}
3. {{∅}}
4. {1,∅}
5. {1,{∅}}
6. {∅,{∅}}
7. {1, ∅,{∅}}
8. ?

Comment: that is correct (the number)

Comment: The subset you are missing is $\{\{\emptyset\}\}$ (the set which contains only $\{\emptyset\}$). As for the second question, are you asking whether any set has exactly $9$ subsets? It looks like you know that if $A$ has size $n$, then $A$ has $2^n$ subsets. Can $2^n$ ever equal $9$?

Comment: I misread your list. You should have $\{1\}$, $\{\emptyset\}$ and $\{\{\emptyset\}\}$ instead of $1$, $\emptyset$, and $\{\emptyset\}$. These are the one-element _subsets_ of $A$ (not elements of $A$). Then the subset you are missing is $\emptyset$.

Comment: please read the ask now

Comment: I repeat what I said above: $1$ is not a subset of $A$. $\{1\}$ is. Similarly you should have $\{\emptyset\}$ for 2. and $\{\{\emptyset\}\}$ for 3. Then 8. is $\emptyset$.

Comment: I understand you do not succeed, can you tell me what are the 8 sets? I also I numbered in the question.

Comment: Please don't add irrelevant tags.

Comment: An $n$-element set has $2^n$ subsets. It's not clear whether $a$ has $2$ or $3$ elements. Is $1=\{\emptyset\}$?

Answer (score 2):

You're correct: there are $2^3=8$ subsets of $$A = \{1, \emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\}.$$

The only subset you missed is $\;\emptyset, 
\;$ which is a subset of all sets, and hence, a subset of $A$.

Answer (score 1):

The 8 subsets are

1. $ \emptyset $
2. $\{1\}$
3. $\{\emptyset\}$
4. $\{1,\emptyset\}$
5. $\{\{\emptyset\}\}$
6. $\{1,\{\emptyset\}\}$
7. $\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}$
8. $\{1,\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}$

A subset is a set which every element is in the superset. Every element in $ \emptyset $ (that is none) is also an element in $a$.

Comment: Can you explain why that is the answer? I must justify the answer

Comment: I thought that you where doing this recreationally.

Comment: Justify the answer?  Because each of the three elements may either be an element of a specific subset or not.  So this is a list of all 8 ways two include or disclude each element.